# Why does javaws start only from root account

Tags: download, java, java-applet, jnlp

Seen on a PC running Fedora16

```
javaws -verbose jviewer.jnlp
```

Runs the applet ok when started from the root account.
Fails with FailedDownloadException when started from a normal user's account.
tcpdump shows that no TCP packet is sent out in the second case.
My network has no proxy requirement.
The command's output looks the same, from root or not. Here it is:

```
% javaws -verbose jviewer.jnlp
Java(TM) Web Start 10.0.0.8-fcs Launching: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin/java /usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin/java
    -classpath  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/lib/deploy.jar 
    -Djava.security.policy=file:/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/lib/security/javaws.policy
    -DtrustProxy=true
    -Xverify:remote
    -Djnlpx.home=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin
    -Dsun.awt.warmup=true
    -Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=jviewer.jnlp
    -Djnlpx.remove=true
    -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/lib/plugin.jar
    -Djnlpx.splashport=37732
    -Djnlpx.jvm=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin/java
    com.sun.javaws.Main
    -verbose
    /tmp/javawg9rK2Q
```

Comment: What information is contained in the `FailedDownloadException`?

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry: I just found that javaws was trying to use a proxy whereas it was not supposed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javaws does not understand Firefox "no proxy" exceptions written in the form ip/mask
(jre1.7.0_01, Firefox 10.0)
It worked for root because Firefox used no proxy at all.
My user account uses a proxy, so I had javaws work there by adding the full IP address into Firefox's "no proxy" exceptions setting.